# Python - dividing a user input to display a range of answers

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm having problems with a Python question. The question is to write a function that shows all integers that are cleanly divisble by 13 in the range of (1:x) where x is a user input. 
I'm new to Python and am struggling with this question. I need to have a user input which Python then divides by 13 and displays the answer(s). So, if a user inputs '27', the answers would be '13' and '26'.

My code so far is:

```
    x = int(raw_input('Enter your Number Here: '))
    def divide(x):
cond = True
while cond:
    x % 13 == 0
    print x
else:
    cond = False
    print 'Your number us not divisble by 13'

    divide(x)
```

Comment: You seem to be missing an `if` in the condition.

Comment: Where should I insert the if condition? Does the code look close?

Comment: Useful builtin function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange  Extra info: In some other languages you'll have to create a new variable initialized to the start value and increment it in a loop until it becomes too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can do this:

```
x = int(input("Enter your number here: "))

def divide(x):
    for i in range(1,x):
        if i % 13 == 0:
            print (i)

divide(x)
```

Comment: Oops you're right, it's redundant. Had a similar thing already coded laying around somewhere and didn't even notice it.

Answer (score 0):

`x % 13 == 0` by itself does nothing; it evaluates to True or False, but you then ignore that result. If you want to do something with it, you need to use it in an if condition.

Note also that indentation is important - the else needs to be lined up with the if. There's no need for `while` at all because nothing can change within the loop.

```
if x % 13 == 0:
    print x
else:
    print 'Your number us not divisible by 13'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can do something like:

```
x = 27 / 13

print [13 * i for i in range(1,x+1)]
```

Comment: This would save the iterations and it is very clean approach

Comment: @Matthew Willis Can you up-vote the answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Borrow the back-ported print function Python 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

The following will print all numbers in the range [1..x] inclusive

```
print([y for y in range(1,x+1,1) if y%13==0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just show all multiples of 13 until x, dropping 0:

```
def divide(x):
   print range(0, x, 13)[1:]
```

Demo:

```
>>> divide(27)
[13, 26]
```